# JSF application: websphere loads PhaseListener before ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets, jsf-2

I have found that in WAS8, the static initializer on a `PhaseListener` is being executed before the `ServletContextListener`, creating problems for us, as the phaselistener relies on some initialisations already being done by the context listener.

I presume this is because the static initialiser is being called when the class is loaded, but why is it being loaded ahead of the servlet context listener? I would think that the context listener is about the very first thing to be loaded and run when a web application is started.

Does anyone know why this is happening exactly?

Comment: Even if the ServletContextListener was loaded (by the classloader) before your PhaseListener, it would still not start the application (and the ServletContextListener) until it was finished loading the classes. So that wouldn't change anything. However, the listeners defined in web.xml should be invoked in order as defined, so making sure `PhaseListener` comes after the other listeners, you should be able to do the initialization at listener initialization instead.

Comment: This turned out to be an implementation difference between Mojarra and Apache's implementation. An incorrect setting in websphere loaded the JSF bundled with WAS, while our own needed to be used.